# Example of not smooth morphisim

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to prove an exercise in Hartshorne's. Let $k_0$ be a field of characteristic $p>0$, let $k=k_0(t)$, and let $X\subseteq A_k^2$ be a curve defined by $y^2=x^p-t$. Show that every local ring on $X$ is a regular local ring but $X$ is not smooth over $k$.

For the first statement, a local ring on a point $q$ should be the localization of ring $\mathcal{O}_X$, i.e. $(k[x,y]/y^2-x^p+t)_q$. And a maximal ideal correspondes to a irreducible polynomial in  $(k[x,y]/y^2-x^p+t)$, thus, it is regular local ring.

For the second statement, notice that $0=d(y^2-x^p+t)=2dy-px^{p-1}dx=2dy$, so $\Omega_{X/k}=0$. But $f$ has relative dimension 1, and we conclude that $f$ is not smooth.

I am not sure whether my argument is right. I hope someone can point out my mistake if there is any.

Comment: I think you are making a mistake when you say $\Omega_{X/k}=0$, please check the definition.

Comment: @Mohan - Actually I don't know how to compute $\Omega_{X/k}$ explictly, and I hope someone could help me. It only need to show that $dim_k \Omega_{X/k}=0$, and then the conclusion still follows.

Comment: $ y^2' = 2y $  .

Comment: Sorry for the ugly shape of the formula. I needed to put at least 15 characters.

Comment: If you have a curve $X$ defined as $f(x,y)=0$ (valid more generally), the exact sequence for 1-forms is, with $R=k[x,y]$, $Rf\to R/f dx\oplus R/f dy\to |Omega_{X/k}\to 0$, where the left map is $f\mapsto df=f_xdx+f_ydy$. In your case, $f_x=0, f_y=2y$ and so, $\Omega_{X/k}=R/f dx\oplus R/(f,2y) dy$.

Comment: @Mohan- So, does it mean $dim_k(\Omega_{X/k})=2$?